# Microsoft Excel - Restrict cell value to percentage

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I've been able to restrict the value of cells to drop down values, whole numbers, dates, etc.  I'm trying to restrict the value of cells to a percentage.  I don't see percentage as a value for 'Data Validation'.

Is there a way to restrict the entry of a value of a cell to a number percentage?  For example, I want the user to only be able to enter a number.  When that number is entered it's shown as a percentage.

Comment: Aren't you basically still validating that it is a number? You could format the cell as a percentage which would mean so long as the cell is a number, it will become a percentage

Comment: Every number is a percentage. 0.1 is 10%, 0.0001 is 0.01%, 1000 is 100000%. what do you mean by "restrict the value of cells to a percentage"?

Comment: Shown as a percentage of what?  Please add an example.

Comment: Thanks everyone, appreciate all of the help!  Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

*Your problem can easily solved by using Data Validation command, as suggested by ERIC & Blackwood also in comments above.*

I'm assuming input cell are A1:A10.

- Click the Data Validation command.
- Pick Custom.
- And apply this Formula: `=isnumber(A1:A10)`.
- Select Range `A1:A10` and in HOME Tab click Cell Format.
- In Number Category click Percentage.
- Set the Decimal to Zero and finish with OK.

**#** Suppose you enter 12 in Cell `A1` then it will look like `12%`.

Comment: Thank you all so much, appreciate all of the help!!  Problem solved!

Comment: @LostinVA,, happy to help you, if you feel either you can up-vote or accept  this as Answer,, and keep asking :-)